# Bussproofs tree will not compile

Tags: errors, logic, proof-package, bussproofs

I have the following proof tree, which latex says is badly specified.

Here is the TeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{$Sz + t = 0 \dagger$} \AxiomC{$t = 0 \dagger$}
\BinaryInfC{$Sz + 0 = 0$}                                   \AxiomC{$Sz + 0 = Sz$}
                                \BinaryInfC{$Sz = 0$}                                   \AxiomC{$\neg (Sz = 0)$}
                                                        \BinaryInfC{$\bot$}
                                                        \UnaryInfC{$\neg(Sz + t) = 0$}





\AxiomC{$\neg(t = 0)$}
\UnaryInfC{$\exists w (t = Sw)$}    
                                                \AxiomC{$t = Sy \dagger$}   \AxiomC{$Sz + t = 0 \dagger$}
                                                        \BinaryInfC{$S(z + y) = 0$}                     \AxiomC{$\neg(S(z + y) = 0$}
                                                                                    \BinaryInfC{$\bot$}
                                                                                    \UnaryInfC{$\neg(Sz + t = 0)$}


\BinaryInfC{$\neg(Sz + t) = 0$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

There are two proof trees, with conclusions `$\neg(Sz + t = 0)$` (both of them), and I want to join those together to conclude `$\neg(Sz + t = 0)$`. I tested it a bit, and it seems the mistake is in the second tree (If I remove the second tree and conclusion it works), but I can't find it.

Comment: Can you please make your code fragment compilable? And the image of the source isn't really needed.

Comment: @AlanMunn what does fragment compilable mean?

Comment: You have posted a fragment of code, i.e., a small piece of code that cannot by itself be compiled. Instead of doing that, put the code you posted inside a `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{bussproofs}\begin{document} ... \end{document}`. This way people can just copy the code to play with it. It also loads the correct package for the `prooftree` environment.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want the output to look like, but if you put `\DisplayProof` after the first tree then the code works. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @AlanMunn almost, but not quite. This gives two proof trees under each other, I want to combine those proof trees into a new one with conclusion $\neg(Sz + t = 0)$

Comment: You have a unary inference command following two formulae and that's the last line. So the second tree ends with two active branches and that's not well-formed. You can make it compile in various ways, but I don't know which of them is the one you want. What is exists-w-t-is-Sw supposed to be a premise in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem is that you have two active branches in the second subtree when you give `\UnaryInfC` as the last line, which won't work because you then have three active branches when you issue `\BinaryInfC` on the last line of all.

The code can be made to compile in various ways, but it isn't possible to know which is correct without knowing more about the semantics and syntax of the language being used.

Here's one way, just as an illustration.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs,geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{$Sz + t = 0 \dagger$} \AxiomC{$t = 0 \dagger$}
  \BinaryInfC{$Sz + 0 = 0$}                                   \AxiomC{$Sz + 0 = Sz$}
  \BinaryInfC{$Sz = 0$}                                   \AxiomC{$\neg (Sz = 0)$}
  \BinaryInfC{$\bot$}
  \UnaryInfC{$\neg(Sz + t) = 0$}

  \AxiomC{$\neg(t = 0) \dagger$}
  \UnaryInfC{$\exists w (t = Sw)$}    
  \UnaryInfC{$t = Sy$}   
  \AxiomC{$Sz + t = 0 \dagger$}
  \BinaryInfC{$S(z + y) = 0$}                     
  \AxiomC{$\neg(S(z + y) = 0$}
  \BinaryInfC{$\bot$}
  \UnaryInfC{$\neg(Sz + t = 0)$}

  \BinaryInfC{$\neg(Sz + t) = 0$}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image: One possibly intended result]

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted, thank you.